# add php variable to aray

Tags: php, variables

```
$devdomain      = $_POST[devdomain];
$maindomain     = $_POST[maindomain];
$username   = $_POST[username];
$package    = $_POST[package];

$sock->set_login("admin|getuser","pass");'

$sock->query('/CMD_API_DOMAIN',
        array(
                'action' => 'create',
                'domain' => $devdomain.$maindomain,
                'cgi' => 'on',
                'php' => 'on',
                'ssl' => 'on',
                'get_package' => 'ON',
                'create' => 'Create'
    ));
```

Can anybody help me how can i get username and package name from variable?

I try:

```
$sock->set_login("'admin|'$username.',"pass");'
```

and

```
$package => 'ON',
```

But in this case something went wrong and script no working. Thanks for correct me.

Comment: Get rid of the `'` characters: `"admin|$username"`

Comment: Its far from clear what you are trying to do and why its not working. You ask how to get 2 values "from variable" when that appears to be exactly the first thing the code above does. We've no idea how you tested this, what the class included does, what you want the code, what is actually happenning when you run this.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong syntax getting your post variables missing ' or ".

```
$devdomain      = $_POST["devdomain"];
$maindomain     = $_POST["maindomain"];
$username   = $_POST["username"];
$package    = $_POST["package"];
```